# Doctrine + ZF + phpunit

Tags: doctrine-1.2

I have ZF 1.11 integrated with Doctrine 1.2 + MySQL 5. I created some phpunit's tests in few files. Every test create db and populate it - using Zend_Db - then I make some actions using Doctrine's models and then I drop db using Zend_Db. I put them all in directory called "tests". And when I go to directory "tests" and write phpunit command then some of them return errors like "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'here_db_name.here_table_name' doesn't exist". - but it exists, I checked! What is funny when I run every test separately then absolutly everything is ok. So, my question is: What's going on? Sorry, I can't provide code.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky to say without any code but I am making a wild guess here that if you say that every test creates and populates the db it might be that what you are experiencing is some sort of a "race-condition" because each test starts with cleaning up the database and then setting it up again.